# JS Hangman - Logic logs wins for single word solutions but not multi-word solutions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the game to update the HTML with the last correct letter(s) first before logging and alerting the win.

Example: "phi_ co__ins", pressing "l" and having them all print to the div, showing "phil collins" BEFORE logging/alerting the win instead of pressing "l" and having it log/alert the win without showing all of the letters, leaving "phi_ co__ins" before the game starts over.

My code will log final letters on multi-word guesses but will not log the win whereas the single words won't display the last correct letter but will register the win and refresh.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I've only found 2 examples and could not adapt either one to fit my needs.

My HTML and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Hangman</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <img src="assets/images/background.png" class="header-img" alt="80's picture">
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Press a letter to get started!</h2>
    <div class="row">        
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div id="game">         
          <h4><h4 id="win-counter">Wins: </h4></h4>
          <h4><h4 id="loss-counter">Losses: </h4></h4>
          <h4>Wrong Guesses: </h4>
          <h5 id="wrong-guesses"></h5>
          <h4>Guesses Remaining: <span id="guesses-left"></span></h4></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div id="play">
          <h3>Guess the singer or band!</h3>
          <br>
          <div><h4 id="wordToGuess"></h4></div>
          <br>
          <div id="hintClue">
            <button id="hint" class="btn btn-sm">Hint</button>
          <h5 id="clue">Song: </h5>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="empty-div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>      

 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



// GLOBAL VARIABLES
// ==================================================

// Array of word options
var bands = ["bangles", "pat benatar", "bon jovi", "david bowie", "chicago", "phil collins", "culture club"];

var selectedWord; // Stores random-selected word
var numBlanks; // # of blanks based in "selectedWord"
var letterGuessed; // Stores the letter guessed
var lettersInWord = []; // Stores the individual letters of each word
var blanksAndSuccesses = []; // Stores mix of blanks & solved letters
var wrongGuesses = []; // Stores wrong guesses

// Game counters
var winCounter = 0;
var lossCounter = 0;
var guessesLeft = 15;

// Get Elements
var wordHolder = document.getElementById("wordToGuess");
var showGuessesLeft = document.getElementById("guesses-left");
var wrong = document.getElementById("wrong-guesses");
var win = document.getElementById("win-counter");
var loss = document.getElementById("loss-counter");
var getHint = document.getElementById("hint");
var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");

// FUNCTIONS
// =======================================================

// play() will start and restart game
function play() {

  // Reset Variables
  guessesLeft = 15;
  blanksAndSuccesses = [];
  wrongGuesses = [];
  showClue.innerHTML = "";

  // Solution chosen randomly from bands array
  selectedWord = bands[Math.floor(Math.random() * bands.length)];

  // Breaks solution word into individual letters
  lettersInWord = selectedWord.split("");

  // Counts the number of letters in the word
  numBlanks = lettersInWord.length;

  // Print solution in console (for testing)
  // console.log(selectedWord);

  // Fill "blanksAndSuccesses" list with appropriate number of blanks, based on number of letters in solution word
  for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {
    if (lettersInWord[i] === " ") {
      blanksAndSuccesses.push("&nbsp;");
    } else {
      blanksAndSuccesses.push("_");
    }
  }

  // Print initial blanks in console
  console.log(blanksAndSuccesses);

  // Reset all HTML variables
  showGuessesLeft.innerHTML = guessesLeft;
  wordHolder.innerHTML = blanksAndSuccesses.join(" ");
  wrong.innerHTML = wrongGuesses.join(" ");
}

// checkLetters() function - holds all comparisons for matches
function checkLetters(letter) {

  // Boolean will be toggled based on if user's letter is found anywhere in the word
  var letterInWord = false;

  // Checks if letter exists inside the array at all
  for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {

    if (selectedWord[i] === letter) {

      // If letter exists, then toggle boolean to true, used in next step
      letterInWord = true;
    }
  }

  // If letter exists somewhere in word, figure out exactly where (which indices)
  if (letterInWord) {

    // Loop through the word
    for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {

      // Populate blanksAndSuccesses with every instance of the letter
      if (selectedWord[i] === letter) {

        // Set specific blank space(s) to equal correct letter when there is a match
        blanksAndSuccesses[i] = letter;
      }
    }

    // Log current blanks and successes for testing
    console.log(blanksAndSuccesses);
  }

  // If letter doesn't exist at all...
  else {

    // Add letter to list of wrong letters
    wrongGuesses.push(letter);

    // Also subtract one of the guesses
    guessesLeft--;

  }
}

// hint() will give hint when button is clicked
hint.onclick = function () {

  hints = ["Manic Monday", "Love is a Battlefield", "Wanted: Dead or Alive", "Let's Dance", "You're the Inspiration", "Sussudio", "Karma Chameleon"];

  var hintIndex = bands.indexOf(selectedWord);
  showClue.innerHTML = "Clue: " + hints[hintIndex];
};

// roundComplete() function - will run necessary code after each guess is made
function roundComplete() {

  // Log initial status in console re: how many wins, losses, and guesses are left
  console.log("Guesses Remaining: " + guessesLeft);

  // Update HTML to reflect new number of guesses
  showGuessesLeft.innerHTML = guessesLeft;

  // Print array of guesses and blanks onto page
  wordHolder.innerHTML = blanksAndSuccesses.join(" ");

  // Print wrong guesses to page
  wrong.innerHTML = wrongGuesses.join(" ");

  // If word guess string equals solution
  if (lettersInWord.toString() === blanksAndSuccesses.toString()) {

    winCounter++; // Add to the win correctGuesses
    alert("You Win!"); // Give user "win" alert   

    // Update win correctGuesses in HTML
    win.innerHTML = "Wins: " + winCounter;

    // Restart game
    play();
  }

  // if user has run out of guesses
  else if (guessesLeft === 0) {

    lossCounter++; // Add to loss correctGuesses
    alert("You Lose!"); // Give user "lose" alert    

    // Update loss correctGuesses in HTML
    loss.innerHTML = "Losses: " + lossCounter;

    // Restart game
    play();    
  }    
}

// MAIN PROCESS
// =======================================================

// Starts game
play();

// Then initiates function for capturing key clicks
document.onkeyup = function (event) {

  // captures keypress, eliminating repeat letters
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    letterGuessed = event.key;

    if (wrongGuesses.indexOf(letterGuessed) !== -1) {
      alert("You already guessed that letter.");
      return;
    }

    // Runs code to check for correct guesses
    checkLetters(letterGuessed);

    // Runs code that ends each round
    roundComplete();    
  }    
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the console output of the two arrays:

```
lettersInWord.toString()
> "p,a,t, ,b,e,n,a,t,a,r"
blanksAndSuccesses.toString()
> "p,a,t,&nbsp;,b,e,n,a,t,a,r"
```

So they are not equal because you've used &nbsp; to represent the space. Maybe try with

```
// If word guess string equals solution
if (!blanksAndSuccesses.includes('_')) {
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  It gives me more insight as I study the logic necessary to accomplish such things.